# Is it ok to ask for code review of a git repository that I have developed?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it is ok to ask for code review of a git repository that I have developed?

I have developed a library for circuit breaker pattern for async functions in C# and I wanted to submit it for code review.

Is it ok to post it?

Comment: If you're asking if it's ok to post just the link to a Git repository, that's not ok. The code to review must be included in the question, and only the code included in the question will be reviewed.

Comment: If [this question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/can-i-put-my-code-on-a-third-party-site-and-link-to-the-site-in-my-question) doesn't answer your question please add more information about what your question is.